# Why from inside Anaconda environment able to access outside packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using Anaconda3 on Windows 10. I created an environment along with one package:

```
conda create -n myenv flask
```

Activated:

```
activate myenv
```

used the following command to check my packages in myenv:

```
conda list
```

It showed a few packages including flask. Then I executed the following one line using Python:

```
import nltk
```

It worked even though nltk was not included in myenv.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

anaconda env also has pip environment.

Check with `pip list | grep -i "nltk"`

`nltk` should be there.

Comment: Hi Vikash and thank you for the answer but I'm not sure to get it.
Do you mean the pip list could be different from the conda one?
And if so how to prevent that to append?